# Convert doc to docx or pdf in python

Tags: python, ms-word

I have to run this conversion method (convert from .doc to .docx and .pdf) in Linux. Can someone help me how to do this please. For obvious reason, win32com.client or comtypes.client doesn't work in Docker - Linux. What are the packages I have to install via pip and via apt-get. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on python 3.9 on Ubuntu 18.04

Using pip you can install doc2pdf

```
from doc2pdf import convert
convert("filename.doc")
```

It will save the file in pdf format to the same directory as the original doc file.